# Is there a way to gauge the contribution of each unit in a fixed effects regression?

Tags: econometrics, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

Suppose we run a regression with one key independent variable and also include group fixed effects.

Is there a way to find out which groups contribute towards the observed results?

Comment: Sure. But what do you want to do with the fixed effects? Do you want to visualize them? There are quite a fews ways to go about reporting/displaying the unit- and/or time-specific effects, though none of them are appealing in my estimation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Software will help you extract and visualize the fixed effects so you can get a handle on their contribution to the model fit. In R, `fixef()` is a helper function that can be found in numerous packages. It will return a list of the fixed coefficients in whatever dimension that's most appealing to you.

Let's look at a very quick example. After loading the `Produc` dataset in R, I will regress the unemployment rate on state output, then adjust for state and year fixed effects. I am a bit partial to the `feols()` funciton in the `fixest` package, so let's go ahead and estimate the model and then extract the fixed effects.

```
# library(fixest)

mod <- feols(unemp ~ gsp | state + year, data = Produc)  # Estimate
fe <- fixef(mod)                                         # Extract
summary(fe)                                              # Summarize
```

```
Fixed_effects coefficients
                        state year
Number of fixed-effects    48   17
Number of references        0    1
Mean                     5.95 1.97
Standard-deviation       2.19 1.49

COEFFICIENTS:
  state: ALABAMA ARIZONA ARKANSAS CALIFORNIA COLORADO                 
           6.904   5.433    5.711      13.49    4.366 ... 43 remaining
-----
  year: 1970   1971   1972     1973   1974                 
           0 0.8031 0.3987 -0.07369 0.5803 ... 12 remaining
```

The output offers a neat summary of the overall mean and standard deviation. We can see that most of the heterogeneity is *across states*. By construction, the elements of the first fixed effect dimension (i.e., state) will not be used as references. In the second dimension, however, we see the year 1970 was set as a common reference for us.

Once we store the results, the `plot()` function centers, sorts, and visualizes the "most notable" (i.e., highest and lowest) of the fixed effects.

```
plot(fe)
```

[image: Fixed Effects - Centered & Sorted]

To be honest, the plot was a little cluttered so I used state abbreviations and omitted some of the state effects. I only did this for ease of viewing. Note California's unemployment rate relative to the national average. I should note that the interpretive value of these plots become a bit murky in settings with *unbalanced* fixed effects across multiple dimensions. Results will also differ in the presence of the state effects alone. I recommend this more so as a visualization tool.

Comment: Thanks for this example Thomas. On the interpretation, it is my understanding that these coefficients are essentially the within-unit mean of the outcome variable after conditioning on any independent variables. I suppose I am more interested in whether it is possible to gauge which units drive the relationship between the outcome  and the key independent variable. E.g. is the relationship between unemployment and state output stronger within certain states than others?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The state effects represent fixed intercepts. In words, states have different starting points but the *same slope* over time. Do you want each state to have a unique slope? Maybe consider allowing your groups (i.e., subjects, districts, states, etc.) to have their own slope by fitting “random slopes” for your particular time variable. This is something to consider, but it’s a bit outside the scope of your current question.