# How to compare the importance of fixed effects with that of explanatory variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

My dependent variable is a share of workers on long term contracts. I test the effect of 10 variables, including topographic factors, population density, availability of alternative employment opportunities etc. I have a panel dataset and use plm to run a fixed-effects regression and get the coefficients plus a set of fixed effects by county. The objective of my study is to rank the variables by their relative importance, and I do this by comparing the coefficients in a standardized form. My question is how to compare the importance of variables with the fixed effects. To be more specific, the estimate for the largest coefficient which is
log(population density) = -0.11, and the mean(fixed effects) = 0.28
Does this mean that the fixed effects are three times more important in explaining the variation of the dependent variable?

Comment: Fixed effects usually *are* explanatory variables.

Comment: Could you explain this? Say my variables are x1, x2,.., x10. The model produces estimates for the intercept for each area so that the predicted value = this intercept + coefficients x values. This way, the FEs are summed up with the effects of explanants. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not a big proponent of standardizing coefficients when working with panel data. Review my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/463370/do-we-need-to-demean-and-standardize-all-variables-in-a-model) where I discuss some reasons why. Others may have a different view. That being said, if you want to visualize the areal unit fixed effects and assess their contribution to the model fit, then my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579034/is-there-a-way-to-gauge-the-contribution-of-each-unit-in-a-fixed-effects-regress) may offer some value.

Comment: The whole literature and nomenclature in this area gets confusing. But, in your example, "county" would be explanatory.  It might be fixed or random. (Some people have advocated against using "fixed" and "random" as they get so confusing and are used in different ways.

Comment: One definition is that fixed effects are ones where you would pick the same "levels' of the variable if you did it again, while random effects are those where you would not do this.

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you very much for your comment. I have looked at the answer you have referred to, and want to ask one specific question. To continue your code: library(fixest)
data(Produc)
mod <- feols(unemp ~ gsp | state + year, data = Produc)  
fe <- fixef(mod)
festate <- fe$state %>% as.data.frame()   
states <- Produc$state %>% unique()
festate <- cbind(festate, states) %>% setNames(c('fe', 'state'))
Produc1 <- left_join(Produc, festate, by = 'state')
yhat <- predict(mod)
Produc1_y70 <- cbind(Produc1, yhat) %>% filter(year == 1970)

Comment: Let's say in 1970 Alabama had observed unemployment rate of 4.7, the model predicted yhat of 6.3, and the FE was 6.9. The prediction was based on two parameters: the gsp, included in the model, and the FE. Which parameter was more important, gsp or the FE?